# Error in ItemAutoTextAdapter

Tags: android, database, search, dictionary

I have a Database Helper. This is my current code in time attack. It has a timer, 16imagebuttons and when clicked, they give a string in a textview. My problem is .. how can i search the word in the textview in database using a button?

```
package com.thesis.boggleit;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.thesis.boggleit.MyDictionary.ItemAutoTextAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TimeAttack extends Activity{

    protected static final String TAG = null;

    String generatedString = " ";
    String Word;

    TextView text, timer;

    ImageButton image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8,
    image9, image10, image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16;

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timeHasStarted = false;

    class ItemAutoTextAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        private MyDbHelper mDbHelper;

        public ItemAutoTextAdapter(MyDbHelper dbHelper) {
            // Call the CursorAdapter constructor with a null Cursor.
            super(TimeAttack.this, null);
            mDbHelper = dbHelper;
        }


        @Override
        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
                return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
            }

            Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getDialect(
            (constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));
            return cursor;
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Word"));
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            final String text = (String) convertToString(cursor);
            ((TextView) view).setText(text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time_attack);

        MyDbHelper dbHelper = new MyDbHelper(this);

        image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        image3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        image4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
        image5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
        image6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
        image7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
        image8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
        image9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
        image10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
        image11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
        image12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
        image13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
        image14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button14);
        image15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button15);
        image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);

        timer = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timer.setText("00:00:30");
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000,1000);

        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);

        final ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        final ImageButton image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        final ImageButton image3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        final ImageButton image4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
        final ImageButton image5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
        final ImageButton image6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
        final ImageButton image7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
        final ImageButton image8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
        final ImageButton image9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
        final ImageButton image10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
        final ImageButton image11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
        final ImageButton image12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
        final ImageButton image13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
        final ImageButton image14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button14);
        final ImageButton image15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button15);
        final ImageButton image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);


        final int[] myPics = { R.drawable.lettera, R.drawable.letterb, R.drawable.letterc, R.drawable.lettere,R.drawable.letteri, R.drawable.lettero, R.drawable.letteru, R.drawable.letterd, R.drawable.letterf, R.drawable.letterg,R.drawable.letterh, R.drawable.letterj, R.drawable.letterk, R.drawable.letterl, R.drawable.letterm, R.drawable.lettern,R.drawable.letterp, R.drawable.letterq, R.drawable.letterqu, R.drawable.letterr,R.drawable.letters, R.drawable.lettert, R.drawable.letterv,R.drawable.letterw, R.drawable.letterx, R.drawable.lettery, R.drawable.letterz };

        int rando = (int)(Math.random()* 5);
        image1.setImageResource(myPics[rando]);
        image1.setId(myPics[rando]);

        int rando1 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image2.setImageResource(myPics[rando1]);
        image2.setId(myPics[rando1]);

        int rando2 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image3.setImageResource(myPics[rando2]);
        image3.setId(myPics[rando2]);

        int rando3 = (int)(Math.random()* 6);
        image4.setImageResource(myPics[rando3]);
        image4.setId(myPics[rando3]);

        int rando4 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image5.setImageResource(myPics[rando4]);
        image5.setId(myPics[rando4]);


        int rando5 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image6.setImageResource(myPics[rando5]);
        image6.setId(myPics[rando5]);

        int rando6 = (int)(Math.random()* 7);
        image7.setImageResource(myPics[rando6]);
        image7.setId(myPics[rando6]);


        int rando7 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image8.setImageResource(myPics[rando7]);
        image8.setId(myPics[rando7]);

        int rando8 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image9.setImageResource(myPics[rando8]);
        image9.setId(myPics[rando8]);

        int rando9 = (int)(Math.random()* 7);
        image10.setImageResource(myPics[rando9]);
        image10.setId(myPics[rando9]);

        int rando10 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image11.setImageResource(myPics[rando10]);
        image11.setId(myPics[rando10]);

        int rando11 = (int)(Math.random()* 8);
        image12.setImageResource(myPics[rando11]);
        image12.setId(myPics[rando11]);

        int rando12 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image13.setImageResource(myPics[rando12]);
        image13.setId(myPics[rando12]);

        int rando13 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image14.setImageResource(myPics[rando13]);
        image14.setId(myPics[rando13]);

        int rando14 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
        image15.setImageResource(myPics[rando14]);
        image15.setId(myPics[rando14]);

        int rando15 = (int)(Math.random()* 5);
        image16.setImageResource(myPics[rando15]);
        image16.setId(myPics[rando15]);

        ItemAutoTextAdapter adapter = this.new ItemAutoTextAdapter(dbHelper);
        text.setAdapter(adapter);
        text.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);

        OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());

                if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.lettera){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                    generatedString = generatedString+ "A"; //[PLACEE RESPACTIVE CHARACTEER HERE]
                    text.setText(generatedString);


                    if (!timeHasStarted) {
                        countDownTimer.start();
                        timeHasStarted = true;
                    }
                    (other buttons ..)

                }

            };

            image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image2.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image3.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image4.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image5.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image6.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image7.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image8.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image9.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image10.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image11.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image12.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image13.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image14.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image15.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
            image16.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);

        }


        public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
            public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                System.out.println(hms);
                timer.setText(hms);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timer.setText("Time's Up!");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIME'S UP!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Please Help ..

Comment: cannot instantiate TimeAttack.ItemAutoTextAdapter

Comment: Post the full logcat

Comment: Also make sure you copied your code correctly. Because `AdapterView&lt;?&gt` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `text` as a TextView:

```
final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
```

[According to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) there is no `setAdapter` or `setOnItemClickListener` method for it. So this lines will throw an error.

```
text.setAdapter(adapter);
text.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);
```

If you want to set an adapter please check ListView for example.

Comment: My xml file has a textview, 16 image button and a listview. Each imagebutton will display a text on textView according to the image on it. After forming an atleast 4letter word, the text in the textview should search the database by clicking a button. If the word is included in the database, the text will be transfered into the listview, else it would be deleted in the textbox.

Comment: Thats why I am using a textview :( I dont know how to do that .. @Pedro Oliveira

Comment: As said in the answer. TextView can't receive an adapter. I don't know where did you see it but this is not the way to do it.

Comment: i tried to put it in listview, the errors are gone, but whenever i run the app, it ends/close. :(

Comment: I dont know how to do it anymore, i've read alot of this and tried mostof them but then it doesnt work. Can anyone help me with this :( I really need to make this work ..

Comment: Instead of doing the check in the textview why don't you check on the onClickListener of the imageviews? After you click a imageview check if the textview has 4 letters and perform the search.